# Lentitud de respuesta de base de datos POSTGRES 9.2 desde web

Tags: postgresql, perl

Requiero consultar 527605 registros de la base de datos de PostgreSQL en Linux CentOS 7. Al realizar las consultas en PostgreSQL la respuesta es rápida, sin embargo vía WEB la respuesta ES EXCESIVAMENTE LENTA.

EXPLAIN de una consulta es la siguiente:

```
db=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT subestacion,date(fecha_24), to_char(fecha_24,'HH24:MI') as HH_MM,valor FROM t_mediciones WHERE subestacion='EDO' AND fecha_24::text LIKE '2021-05-%' ORDER BY fecha_24;

                                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=15844.52..15847.76 rows=1295 width=20)
         (actual time=299.200..302.464 rows=22975 loops=1)
   Sort Key: fecha_24
   Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 1120kB
   Buffers: shared hit=2753 read=2466, temp read=140 written=140
   ->  Seq Scan on t_mediciones  (cost=0.00..15777.58 rows=1295 width=20) (actual time=36.677..273.660 rows=22975 loops=1)
         Filter: ((subestacion = 'EDO'::bpchar) AND ((fecha_24)::text ~~ '2021-05-%'::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 504630
         Buffers: shared hit=2753 read=2466
 Total runtime: 304.855 ms
(9 rows)
 
db=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT subestacion,date(fecha_24), to_char(fecha_24,'HH24:MI') as HH_MM,valor FROM t_mediciones WHERE subestacion='EDO' AND fecha_24::text LIKE '2021-09-%' ORDER BY fecha_24;
                             QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=15844.52..15847.76 rows=1295 width=20)
         (actual time=276.338..278.983 rows=19242 loops=1)
   Sort Key: fecha_24
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 936kB
   Buffers: shared hit=2785 read=2434, temp read=118 written=118
   ->  Seq Scan on t_mediciones  (cost=0.00..15777.58 rows=1295 width=20) (actual time=15.882..264.575 rows=19242 loops=1)
         Filter: ((subestacion = 'EDO'::bpchar) AND ((fecha_24)::text ~~ '2021-09-%'::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 508363
         Buffers: shared hit=2785 read=2434
 Total runtime: 280.953 ms
(9 rows)
```

En PostgreSQL realicé las siguientes actualizaciones:

```
  # El parámetro shared_buffers, inicialmente tenía configurado 24 MB y lo actualicé a 1 GB.
  #vim postsgresql.conf
  shared_buffers= 1 GB
  #sudo systemctl restart postgresql
  # Actualización del parámetro shared_buffers:
  db=#show work_mem;
       1MB
  #Actualización:
  db=#set work_mem to ‘1GB’;
  postgres=#show work_mem;
  1 GB
```

El código en Perl 9.2 es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;

    use CGI qw(:standard);
    use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
    use v5.8.8;
    use strict;
    use perlchartdir;
    use Encode;
    use Date::Calc qw(Delta_Days); #Date::Calc - Gregorian calendar date calculations
    use Date::Manip;  #Date manipulation routines-Operations such as comparing two times, determining a date a given amount of time from another
    use DateTime;
    use DBI;

    use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
    use utf8;  #utf8 - Perl pragma to enable/disable UTF-8 IN SOURCE CODE: Indica a perl que el programa está escrito en utf8
    use open qw(:std :utf8);
    use Date::Range;
    use POSIX;
    print "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n"; ######---Esta linea dice, que de aquí en adelante todo el "print" se va a desplegar como HTML.
    
        # Obtenemos los parámetros seleccionados
        my $query=new CGI;
    
    #######################################################################
    ###------------ VARIABLES DE CONEXIÓN A LA BASE DE DATOS ------------##
    
        my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=icev;host=localhost", "xochitl", "", {'RaiseError' => 1});
        my $sth; my $sql;my $mvar_med; my $reg_med; my $reg_dcev;
        my $sql_valor; my $hm; my $valor; my $aux_valor;
        my $idxMin; my $sql_min_event; my $tuplas; my $idx=0; my %h_FechaValor;
        my $date;my $AuxdateFinParam; 
    
    ##----------- OBTENEMOS LOS PARÁMETROS SELECCIONADOS-----------##
    my $cve_inst= $query->param("cve_inst");
    my $dateIniParam= $query->param("date1");
    
    my $AuxdateIniParam=$dateIniParam;
    $AuxdateIniParam=~ s/\//-/g ;
    my $date1ORI= $dateIniParam;
    my @dateIniAux= split("/",$dateIniParam); # 2021 01 01 -Creo un arreglo para acceder por índice
    $dateIniParam.=' 00:01';
    my $datIni= DateTime->new(
            year  => $dateIniAux[0],
            month => $dateIniAux[1],
            day   => $dateIniAux[2],
    );
    my $datIniDate= substr($datIni,0,10);
    print "INICIO: $datIniDate<br>";
    my $y1= $datIni->year;
    my $m1= $datIni->month;
    my $d1= $datIni->day;
    
    my $date1 = ParseDate($dateIniParam);
    
    #####HASTA AQUÍ ESTÁ BIEN
    
    my $dateFinParam= $query->param("date2");
    print "DATEFINPARAM=$dateFinParam<br>";
    my $AuxdateFinParam=$dateFinParam;
    
    $AuxdateFinParam=~ s/\//-/g ;
    
    my $date2ORI= $dateFinParam;
    
    my @dateFinAux= split("/",$dateFinParam); #2021 01 01 -Creo un arreglo para acceder por índice
    $dateFinParam.=' 23:59';
    my $datFin= DateTime->new(
            year  => $dateFinAux[0],
            month => $dateFinAux[1],
            day   => $dateFinAux[2],
    );
    my $y2= $datFin->year;
    my $m2= $datFin->month;
    my $d2= $datFin->day;
    
    my $date2 = ParseDate($dateFinParam);
    
    my $diferencia= DateCalc($date2,$date1);
    
    my @dias_diff= split(":",$diferencia);
    my $dias_diff= $dias_diff[4]/24; #----obtención de días
    
    my $dias_totales=floor($dias_diff);
    $dias_totales=$dias_totales*-1;
    
    my %time_value = ();
    my @row; my $reg_med_cev; my $sql_HM; my $idx_row=0;
    my $sub; my $fecha; my$hor_min; my $aux_hor_min; my $val;
    my @periodo_fechas;
    my $inicio; my $range;
    my $h_key; my $tot_valor;
    my $hora;  my $minuto; my @minuto; my $aux_datini;
    
    do{
        printf "<b>FECHA:</b> %s\n", $datIni->ymd('-');
        foreach ( 00 .. 23  ){ ###HORA###
                $hora=$_;
                foreach ( 00 .. 59  ){ ###MINUTO###
                        my $tiempo= sprintf("%02d:%02d",$hora,$_); #Creación de variable tiempo adicionando 0
                        print "<b>H/MIN:</b> $hora:$tiempo <br>";
                        my $aux_datini= $datIni->ymd('-');  #Guardo la primera fecha AAAA-MM=DD
                        
                        $sql_HM="SELECT subestacion,date(fecha_24), to_char(fecha_24,'HH24:MI') as HH_MM,valor FROM t_mediciones WHERE subestacion='$cve_inst' AND fecha_24::text LIKE '$aux_datini $tiempo%' ORDER BY fecha_24 FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY";
                        $sth= $dbh->prepare($sql_HM) or die $DBI::errstr;
                        $sth->execute();
                        $tuplas = $sth->rows;
                        if ($tuplas > 0){
                                while($reg_dcev = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
                                        $sub=$reg_dcev->{'subestacion'};
                                        $fecha=$reg_dcev->{'date'};
                                        $hm=$reg_dcev->{'hh_mm'};
                                        $valor=$reg_dcev->{'valor'};  #guardamos el valor recibido
                                        if ($valor == 0){
                                                print "REGISTRO EXISTENTE PERO CON VALOR= CERO";
                                        } # if ($valor == 0)
                                        else{
                                                $aux_valor=$valor; #asignamos a la variable $aux_los el valor recien leído
                                                $tot_valor=+$valor;
                                                print "TOT_VALOR: $tot_valor<br>";
                                                %h_FechaValor= ($fecha,$valor); #poblar el hash
                                        } #end if-else ($valor==SOY CERO)
                                } #while($reg_dcev = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) 
                        } #if ($tuplas > 0) 
                } #END FOREACH MINUTOS
                #print "<b>END FOREACH MINUTOS: FECHA-VALORES: $fecha-$valor</b><br>";
        }# END FOREACH HOUR
        print "<b>END HOURS 00 TO 24!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</b><br>";
    } while ( $datIni->add(days => 1) <= $datFin );
    exit;
```

---

**Gracias por Tu valiosa aportación Joaquín Ferrero** realicé las modificaciones de acuerdo a Tus sugerencia **pero** el módulo **DATE::MANIP** si es requerido ya al eliminarlo el programa manda error: Undefined subroutine &main::ParseDate called at my **$date1=ParseDate($dateIniParam)**
Por la razón anterior la descomentarice  y nuevamente volvió a ver los registros.

Agradeceré tu valiosa sugerencia para adoptar Tus valiosas recomendaciones.

Respetos

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes eliminar o comentar las líneas de los módulos que estás importando y no usando. Por ejemplo, veo que Date::Calc y Date::Manip no los estás usando. Al quitarlos, verás que ganas en velocidad. Lo mismo para Date::Range.

Estos módulos no los necesitas ya que veo que sólo estás usando DateTime. DateTime es un módulo algo lento, pero no tan pesado como Date::Manip.

Vete eliminando módulos hasta que te salga algún error de que falta por cargar ese módulo. Lo repones y sigues con todos y así te quedas con sólo los que realmente necesitas. "Encode" y "use utf8" creo que también sobran. "use open ..." creo que no lo necesitas si lo que estás leyendo de la base de datos/escribiendo en pantalla no está en utf8. Tendrás que probar.

Una vez que compruebes que la salida es correcta (aunque sea lenta), comenta las líneas de carga de los módulos "strict", "Data::Dumper" y "CGI::Carp". Son útiles para el desarrollo y depuración, pero no para producción.

Lo más lento que veo son las consultas: realizas 1440 consultas (24 horas por 60 minutos) por cada día que procesas. Yo lo que haría sería hacer una única consulta por día, leerlo todo a un array, y luego procesar ese array con Perl. Eso es mucho más rápido que hacer 1440 consultas.

Comment: HOLA EXPLORER, SIGUIENDO TUS RECOMENDACIONES LA CONSULTA SE AGILIZÓ EXITOSAMENTE. RESPETOS PARA TI.